# Angularfire auth confirmPasswordReset does not exist on type User

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to implement password reset functionality using the angularfire2/auth class, following along the implementation here: https://medium.com/@c_innovative/implementing-password-reset-can-be-a-tricky-but-inevitable-task-737badfb7bab

My code is basically the same below: but I get an error

"Property 'confirmPasswordReset' does not exist on type     'Observable(User)'

```
handleResetPassword() { 

     if (this.newPassword != this.confirmPassword) { 
       this.matSnackBar.open("Passwords do not match.", null, { duration: 4000 }); 
       return; 
     } 

     // Save the new password. 
     this.authService.getAuth().confirmPasswordReset(
       this.actionCode, 
       this.newPassword
     ).then(resp => { 
       // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.    
       alert('New password has been saved');
       this.router.navigate(['/login']); }).catch(e => { 
         // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have
         // expired or the password is too weak. alert(e); 
       }); 
     }
```

Short of implementing a REST workaround does anyone know why this angularFire auth method seems to not work? it should be a valid function on the auth object.

Answer (score 0):

You must use @angular/fire/auth

1. Inject AngularFireAuth in your constructor
2. From your handleResetPassword Method use the injected property

   ```
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {

      constructor(private fbAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

      handleResetPassword() {
         // call comfirmPasswordReset method like this
     this.fbAuth.auth.confirmPasswordReset(this.actionCode,this.newPassword) 
      }
    }
   ```